# How can I correctly write this event?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, exponential-distribution

> Suppose there are three students wanting to meet a Professor in his office. The time $i$-th student takes with the Professor is $Exponential(\lambda_i)$ distributed, and they are independent. Assume all students start talking to the Professor simultaneously. Find the distribution of the time until only one student is left.

If I denote $T$ to be the desired time and $T_i$ to be the discussion time for $i$-th student, how exactly can I write $\{T\leq x\}$ in terms of $T_i$?

It seems that $\{T\leq x\}=\{T_1\leq x,T_2\leq x\}\cup\{T_2\leq x,T_3\leq x\}\cup\{T_1\leq x,T_3\leq x\}$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is right.  To evaluate the probability, we use Inclusion/Exclusion, getting
$$\Pr(T_2\le x)\Pr(T_3\le x)+\Pr(T_1\le x)\Pr(T_3\le x)+\Pr(T_1\le x) \Pr(T_2\le x)\\-2\Pr(T_1\le x)\Pr(T_2\le x)\Pr(T_3\le x).$$

Comment: If $T>x$ then I think we have to say more: it means that the last person takes more than $x$ time to complete his discussion. But it doesn't really say that BOTH the other two persons HAVE TO complete their discussion within time $[0,x]$. This is where I was having a confusion.

Comment: I also thought of an $(x-\epsilon)$ and $(x+\epsilon)$ argument: like first trying to write this in terms of $x-\epsilon$ and $x+\epsilon$ and then letting $\epsilon\to0$. Not sure though whether it'd work.

Comment: You mean like how one finds distributions of order statistics? That should be OK. I feel I have feet more on the ground working with cdf.

Comment: Thank u for the answer . I actually had thought we were missing out something. I am now convinced its right.

Comment: You are welcome. When you asked about correctness earlier I looked carefully and could not see a problem, Will take a last look, after coffee.

Comment: Sure, and enjoy your coffee!

Comment: @LandonCarter: On third thought I do not like my answer.  Will try to give a clearer analysis. Tried to delete, but was not allowed to because the answer has been accepted. It will take a while, busy morning.

Comment: You need not delete. I think the answer is correct. If you are worried about "presentation", I think it's fine, really!